# How to solve error: Could not find artifact sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, java-16

I get this error after upgrading from Java 8 to Java 16

```
  Could not resolve dependencies for project com.berwick:bds-core:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk at specified path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/jconsole.jar

JAVA_HOME --> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I am using IntelliJ

my pom file

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    ..... 
</properties>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
            <target>${java.version}</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

....
</plugins>
```

I tried to fix the issue by adding this to pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0.CR1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconsole</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I run this command to build the project

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing artifact "sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236195/missing-artifact-sun-jdkjconsolejarjdk)

Comment: What project are you upgrading? Is there a minimal reproducible example for this? There could possibly be a lot of reasons for a project not being able to resolve dependencies.

Comment: Looks like this problem can be solved by upgrading the dependency that is compatible with Java 9 and above since it uses `sun.jdk`. Read the migration guide, specifically about `jdkinternals`.

Comment: I update my question, I am tried a lot of stuff with no luck I wonder where to start

Comment: @MinaFawzy how about upgrading `wildfly-embedded` to its latest version and giving it a shot?