# 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.sun.net.ssl.internal.Provider:tools:jar is missing

Tags: java, maven

I am getting this error while i am executing mvn install command.
I didn't find any dependency version for this dependency, can someone please help me.

Comment: You may want to review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375423/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar

Comment: Forgot to reply back, Thanks for the quick response.