# Missing artifact sun.plugin:plugin:jar:1.7

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm getting this error in Spring Tool Suite when I right-click a project and select Maven->Update Project. When I go to `~/.m2/repository/sun/plugin/plugin`, here is what I see.

> $ ls
>
> m2e-lastUpdated.properties
>   plugin-1.7-javadoc.jar.lastUpdated
>   plugin-1.7-sources.jar.lastUpdated

Apparently the plugin-1.7.jar is missing from my Maven repository. This might be because I stupidly deleted ~/.m2/repository yesterday in order to try to fix another problem.

How do I fix this error? How can I install plugin-1.7.jar? It's the plugin-1.7 jar from com.sun, but when I search Google I can't find where to download it.

Comment: Can you please add your pom.xml. Maybe you have something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375423/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar/12230978) Or maybe you did install the plugin from jdk into your local repository?

Comment: you could also run the maven build from the command line to see if that works, and if not, use the error output to find out more about the underlying issue

Comment: Another thing to try, assuming your pom / project is actually not to blame, is to clear out the `~/.m2/repositories` directory, or less drastically, just the `~/.m2/repository/sun` directory. Assuming the missing artefact actually exists, the error could just be due to some corruption in local maven cache,