# How to find where to put tools.jar exclusion in pom file?

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent project that has multiple sub modules.
Whenever I run `mvn package -DskipTests` at the project root, some submodule breaks on not finding tools.jar in the JDK directory (Mac OS Big Sur).

After some research, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375423/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar) that asks to put an exclusion in the dependency that's expecting tools.jar. I fixed some modules with this solution but it isn't very scalable. My submodules have several dependencies and I have to put exclusion in all of them and build, then undo some exclusions and build again to find out which exact dependency is expecting tools.jar. I have tried running `mvn dependency:tree` to find out but even that fails on the same unable to find tools.jar error. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with Maven - but I guess you should fix your classpath rather than exclude any dependency.

Comment: Did you test using Eclipses dependency view [as suggested by me in the thread you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32871694/365237)?

Comment: @maio290 tools.jar is a relic from older versions of java, which really shouldn't be referred to anymore

Comment: @eis - I don't use Eclipse. I use IntelliJ instead.

Comment: @eis Well - I wouldn't call Java 8 a relic already.

Comment: @maio290 I didn't call java 8 a relic, I called tools.jar :) tools.jar is an artifact of older versions which did linger until java 8 until it died. Even with java 8 it hasn't been a good practice to refer to it. one of the reasons was that it has been called classes.jar on mac instead of tools.jar, causing the build to break per operating system for no reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that helped me was this IntelliJ plugin -
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper

Going to "Dependency Analyzer" and search for "com.sun" pointed me to the exact dependency.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should add tools.jar as an exclusion. I would rather suggest adding tools.jar into your JDK.

If you don't have any tools.jar, I would suggest downloading a new version of JDK, copy tools.jar from the lib folder and copy into your jdk_home/lib.

Following these steps solved my problem when I came across it.

Comment: why would you suggest that? new versions of JDK don't contain tools.jar.