# Eclipse Maven Build fails with tool jar not found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Does anyone know why my eclipse-2020-06 is unable to build my maven project?
The below screenshot shows the error, where it is pointing to the jre location.[image]

```
Error: Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181/../lib/tools.jar
```

1. I have changed the jre in windows->preferences->java->installed JREs,  and I have pointed that to my java jdk location as below and removed the previous path which is shown in the above image.
   Though I change it I still see the error even after restart.
   [image]
2. Also I have tried restarting the Eclipse as well.
   Tried changing the eclipse.ini file by adding

   -vm
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\javaw

And I have gone through couple of similar queries everything points to adding a dependency tool jar which I do not want to as this is working fine in Intelij, so just to resolve the IDE issue I don’t want to end up adding a dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375423/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar)

Comment: What fails? The incremental project builder or running a Maven build? The Java used for running a Maven build has to be configured in the run configuration in the _JRE_ tab. The Java used to run Eclipse is independent from that (what you did in 2. is wrong in several ways).