# How to buld a Maven project with a specified java home property in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to build a maven integrated project with a given java home property. At exactly i want to write a code in java that sets the java home property for an InvocationRequest object. The main goal is to build a project with the runtime given(by an algorithm) java home. So i would call `getInvoker().execute(request);` to execute maven goals where request is an InvocationRequest object.
 
I tried to set the request java.home property with
 `properties.setProperty(Goals.JAVA_HOME, javaHomePath);` and call the method `executeGoals(pom, new String[] { Goals.INSTALL, Goals.CLEAN }, properties);` . 
This executeGoals(...) method contains getInvoker().execute(request) call and the request object definition too. 
 
Output is: `Missing: 1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0` #Solved

**EDIT:** solved the output problem, but a new one appeared: 
`class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0`. Maybe i changed the jre home, so i think i'm compiling with a newer version of java than i'm running with. 

Reminder: i want to build with a specified java home property = i want to change the compiler java home(or version) to the specified one. (In eclipse)

 I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please have a look at following question and the excepted answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756299/maven-3-artifact-problem

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is configurable. It is part of the Maven Core to use the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Please see the accepted answer of:
[How to set specific java version to Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654557/how-to-set-specific-java-version-to-maven)

Also it is not possible to set or change environment variables (not system properties) within a Java process (for the current process). If you create another process from within your Java process, there will be [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])) to specify environment variables for this sub process.

Maybe the solution will be to execute a Maven command e.g. "mvn clean install" with a specific JAVA_HOME variable set as sub process (this requires, that Maven is installed and mvn is available as command). Use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to switch into the working directory, where the pom.xml of the target project is located and set the appropriate [environment variable(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment()) before starting the process.

If Maven should not be installed at the enviroment your application is running on, you could also distribute a Maven installation with your application (maybe in a separate directory). Then you could run against the mvn.bat or mvn.sh of this distribution (depending on the os).

Answer (score 0):

When using Eclipse, Build in `Run as Configuration`, go to the `Environment` tab and add the new `JAVA_HOME` variable.
Do not forget to check the **Replace native environment .....** option.

This will override your default OS variable. No need to change at the OS level.